# Foundation Zurb - container width?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Looked through Foundation zurb documentation. Noted that rows, columns and container are not defined in width as in documentation, but if want the wrapper container to be set at 1000px to wrap header, body, sidebar, footer inside, does the wrapper need to be defined in width to contain everything inside?

Also the header, body, sidebar, footer are placed in each row with medium-# or large-# so that they can be resized according to browser size.

Sorry and I am trying Foundation for the first time.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you properly download all the foundation material (use bower from the command line or you can download a zip from the github page), you'll find:

```
$row-width: emCalc(1000);
```

in the sass files under _settings.scss

You can adjust this, and many other values that affect widths, within this file.

The specified .small or .medium or .large classes for rows are used for foundation's grid layouts and are designed especially for screen widths matching those relevant sizes.  If you're new, I would work with "small columns" first as foundation is designed as a mobile first platform, and it has less problems scaling up than down.  Good luck!

Comment: thanks! I start with medium would it be trouble scaling up and down?

Comment: Medium is used for tablets. you can easily combine grids, such as:
<div class="row">
<div class="small-4 medium-3 large-2"></div>
<div class="small-8 medium-9 large-10></div>
</div>
As you scale, the grids will automatically adjust based on the screen size.
Also, please up vote if you like the answer. I'm new here and trying to shamelessly up my score :)

Comment: thanks yup will tick answer. last question - are u familiar with grid's row collapse? I tried to use it but padding and margin is still not removed.

Comment: to be honest, I usually just use a _custom.scss stylesheet to override aspects of margin and padding in places I want to remove or adjust them.  I just find it easier, as I've had mixed results with customizing the column mixin options in sass.  Hope this helps.